# SQL Server Service Broker notification queue dont fire anymore after waiting for it with a SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, service-broker

(bad grammar warning)
I wanted to get notified everytime a specific table has changed, like a new rows got inserted. It works as long as i dont try to monitor the queue in my SQL Server/SSMS with a query, instead of my program.

I created a new Service and queue like that:

```
CREATE QUEUE SQLDependencyQueue;
CREATE SERVICE NamesService
ON QUEUE SQLDependencyQueue
([http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostQueryNotification]) ;
```

When i now listen to the queue with a little C# program, it works like a charm.

```
 private void InitializGetData()
        {
            String connectionString = "Server=DESKTOP-N943R2B\\SQLEXPRESS01;Database = DBDependency; User Id = sa;Password = admin; ";

            if (conn == null)
            {
                conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            }

            if(command == null)
            {
                command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT[id],[lade_nr],[vg_lfd_nr],[status] FROM[dbo].[t3_auftr_log_ll] where [status] = 0", conn);
            }

            if (dataToWatch == null)
            {
                dataToWatch = new DataSet();
            }

            notification = new SqlNotificationRequestRegister("WAITFOR(RECEIVE * FROM SQLDependencyQueue);", strServiceName, timeOut, connectionString);
            notification.OnChanged += NotificationOnChanged;

            getData();
        }

        void getData()
        {
            if(notification == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            dataToWatch.Clear();

            command.Notification = null;
            command.Notification = notification.NotificationRequest;

            //notification.StartSqlNotification();

            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
            {
                adapter.Fill(dataToWatch, "Order_log_ll");

                for(int i= 0; i <= dataToWatch.Tables["Order_log_ll"].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Row: {0}", dataToWatch.Tables["t3_Auftr_log_ll"].Rows[i]["vg_lfd_nr"].ToString())); //, dataToWatch.Tables["t3_Auftr_log_ll"].Rows[i]["status"].ToString()

                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update t3_auftr_log_ll set status = 1 where id = @id",conn))
                    {
                        if (conn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                        {
                            conn.Open();
                        }
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", dataToWatch.Tables["t3_Auftr_log_ll"].Rows[i]["id"].ToString());
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }

            notification.StartSqlNotification();
        }
```

```
private void RegisterSqlNotificationRequest()
        {
            request = new SqlNotificationRequest();
            request.UserData = new Guid().ToString();
            request.Options = String.Format("Service={0}", strServiceName);
            request.Timeout = intNotificationTimeout;

            if (OnChanged != null)
            {
                OnChanged(this, null);
            }
        }
```

```
public void Listen()
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString))
            {
                using (cmd = new SqlCommand("WAITFOR(RECEIVE * FROM SQLDependencyQueue);", conn))
                {
                    if (conn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                    }

                    cmd.CommandTimeout = intNotificationTimeout + 120;

                    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i <= reader.FieldCount - 1; i++)
                                Debug.WriteLine(reader[i].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            RegisterSqlNotificationRequest();
        }
```

But if i start the program and then call a query in SSMS to see what the queue has in it like that:

```
WAITFOR(RECEIVE * FROM SQLDependencyQueue);
```

or like that:

```
RECEIVE conversation_handle, message_type_name, message_body  
FROM SQLDependencyQueue;
```

The queue stops working. My program is waiting for a notification, but the SQL server dosent create notification after that anymore when i insert something into the table.

When i check if the queue is active like that:

```
select is_receive_enabled
from sys.service_queues
where name = N'SQLDependencyQueue';
```

It shows me "1" for active, but still dont get a notification.

Only if i restart the program and subscribe again to the queue, its works again.

Edit:

When looking at the subcriptions with

```
select * from sys.dm_qn_subscriptions
```

there are two entryies when the program starts (withought a manuell wait). when i also wait extra manuelly for a notification, i thought i get 3 rows then, but the program stops working and in the subscription table left only one row, even tho i stopped the manuell wait.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run a `RECEIVE` manually and get a message back it means you have consumed the notification. In your C# code, after consuming a notification you *subscribe again*. If you consume it from SSMS, then your program won't subscribe again, so you'll end up with the program waiting forever for a notification that was already consumed from the queue, and nobody will re-subscribe.

You can check [`sys.dm_qn_subscriptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/query-notifications-sys-dm-qn-subscriptions?view=sql-server-ver15) for the status of your query notification *subscriptions*.

What most people miss about Query Notifications is that you only get **one** notification, then you must subscribe again. Many expect to subscribe once an then get a stream of notifications, for every change. The feature is designed for cache invalidation (you get the data in the cache with a query, then you get notified when to refresh the cache). It does not work for monitoring a table for changes (which is what you seem to be trying).

Comment: Adding that one can check for messages on the queue in SSMS using a `SELECT` query instead of `RECEIVE` to avoid consuming the notification.

Comment: Why does it not work for monitoring? I mean if i just let the program run and dont make a receive in SSMS myself, it works like i was expecting it. I got a notification everytime the table has changed.

Comment: What i noticed with is, that when the program runs, i have two rows in that table, when it stops working because i manuelly waited for a notification, i only have one row, even when i stop waiting for it manuelly. (added that to my original post)

Comment: It doesn't work because you can miss notifications after you're being notified until you subscribe again.